# How can I convert the varchar2 format value to datetime type in Oracle in my case?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have data in following format-

```
Fri, May 13, 2016 at 10:54 PM
```

The value is inserted as `varchar2` type.

I wanted to convert it to `datetime` type to insert in another column.

How can this be possible?

Comment: use to_date function with appropriate format

Comment: used this to_date('Fri, May 20, 2016 at 6:36 AM', 'Day, Mon mm, yyyy at hh:mi AM') but didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions at all:

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'Fri, May 13, 2016 at 10:54 PM' text_date FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    TO_DATE(text_date, 'DY, Mon DD, YYYY "at" HH:MI AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') adate
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the day, month, year and time from the text string using a regular expression and use `to_date` to convert it to a date:

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'Fri, May 13, 2016 at 10:54 PM' text_date FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(text_date, '(\w{3}), (\w{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4}) at (\d{1,2}:\d{2}) (AM|PM)','\3-\2-\4 \5 \6'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM') adate
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice use of `regex`

Comment: Awesome :) need to check for all values